# What data structure or design pattern to use to map a defined sequence of steps

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, graph-algorithm

We have a java application that processes different types of financial transactions. These transactions have different flows and for system flexibility(esp user) we introduced an xml that we use to define the transaction flow for each. The steps are  executed asynchronously
The xml looks like this

```
<transaction code="201510" name="deposit">

        <step id="1" name="momo.debit" script="step-1" result="0000" nextid="2">
            <error code="0104" script="err-0104"/>
            <error code="5008" script="$err-0301"/>
            <error code="03**" script="err-0300"/>
            <error code="50-98" script="err-5000"/>
        </step>

        <step id="2" name="deposit" script="step-2" result="0000" nextid="3">
            <error code="0105" script="err-0105" hook="2" />
            <error code="0203" script="$err-5000" hook="2"/>
            <error code="0205" script="$err-5000" hook="2"/>
            <error code="0206" script="$err-5000" hook="2"/>
            <error code="6100" script="err-5100" hook="2"/>
            <error code="5001" script="$err-5101" hook="2"/>
            <error code="5002" script="$err-5101" hook="2"/>
            <error code="5003" script="$err-5101" hook="2"/>
            <error code="5004" script="$err-5102" hook="2"/>
            <error code="5005" script="$err-5104" hook="2"/>
            <error code="5006" script="$err-5105" hook="2"/>
            <error code="50-59" script="$err-5107" hook="2"/>
            <error code="6000" script="$err-5108" hook="2"/>
            <error code="6005" script="$err-5106" hook="2"/>
            <error code="60-99" script="$err-5000" hook="2"/>
        </step>

        <step id="3" name="notify" script="$notify" result="*"/>

    </transaction>
```

Synopsis
Each step contains a step script, expected result of the step script, error correction scripts incase the step script fails and also intercepting scripts called hooks which perform some work before executing the step script or error script.

Current Design
I have the following classes

A enum called State

```
enum State {

ERROR, HOOK, STEP, REPLAY;
```

}

A state node that contains all the attributes :

```
final class StateNode implements Serializable {

private final String id;
private final String name;
private final String code;
private final String hook;
private final String replay;
private final String script;
private final String result;
private final String nextid;
private final String advance;
private final States statename;
private boolean errorExecuted = false;
private boolean hookExecuted = false;
private boolean replayExecuted = false;
private boolean scriptExecuted = false;


public StateNode(States statename, Map<String, String> step) {

    this(statename, step.get("id"), step.get("name"), step.get("script"), step.get("result"), step.get("nextid"), step.get("code"), step.get("hook"), step.get("replay"), step.get("advance"));
}

public StateNode(States statename) {
    this(statename, "");
}

public StateNode(States statename, String id) {
    this(statename, id, "");
}

public StateNode(States statename, String id, String name) {
    this(statename, id, name, "");
}

public StateNode(States statename, String id, String name, String script) {
    this(statename, id, name, script, "");
}

public StateNode(States statename, String id, String name, String script, String result) {
    this(statename, id, name, script, result, "");
}

public StateNode(States statename, String id, String name, String script, String result, String nextid) {
    this(statename, id, name, script, result, nextid, "");
}

public StateNode(States statename, String id, String name, String script, String result, String nextid, String code) {
    this(statename, id, name, script, result, nextid, code, "");
}

public StateNode(States statename, String id, String name, String script, String result, String nextid, String code, String hook) {
    this(statename, id, name, script, result, nextid, code, hook, "");
}

public StateNode(States statename, String id, String name, String script, String result, String nextid, String code, String hook, String replay) {
    this(statename, id, name, script, result, nextid, code, hook, replay, "");
}

public StateNode(States statename, String id, String name, String script, String result, String nextid, String code, String hook, String replay, String advance) {
    this.id = id;
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.hook = hook;
    this.nextid = nextid;
    this.replay = replay;
    this.result = result;
    this.script = script;
    this.advance = advance;
    this.statename = statename;
}

public States getStateName() {
    return statename;
}

public String getId() {
    return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(id, "-1");
}

public String getName() {
    return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(name, "");
}

public String getScript() {
    return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(script, "");
}

public String getResult() {
    return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(result, "*");
}

public String getNextid() {
    return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(nextid, "-1");
}

public String getCode() {
    return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(code, "");
}

public String getHook() {
    return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(hook, "");
}

public String getReplay() {
    return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(replay, "");
}

public String getAdvance() {
    return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(advance, "true");
}

public boolean isErrorExecuted() {
    return errorExecuted;
}

public void setErrorExecuted(boolean errorExecuted) {
    this.errorExecuted = errorExecuted;
}

public boolean isHookExecuted() {
    return hookExecuted;
}

public void setHookExecuted(boolean hookExecuted) {
    this.hookExecuted = hookExecuted;
}

public boolean isReplayExecuted() {
    return replayExecuted;
}

public void setReplayExecuted(boolean replayExecuted) {
    this.replayExecuted = replayExecuted;
}

public boolean isScriptExecuted() {
    return scriptExecuted;
}

public void setScriptExecuted(boolean scriptExecuted) {
    this.scriptExecuted = scriptExecuted;
}
```

}

A state tree that stores all steps being executed (Statenode) of a transaction in flight within the system

final class StateTree implements Serializable {

```
private int maxsteps = 0;
private final Map<Integer, StateNode> branches;

public StateTree() {
    this.branches = new LinkedHashMap();
}

public int getPoint() {
    return branches.size();
}

public State getParentState(int point) {
    return branches.get(point - 1).getStateName();
}

public StateNode getCurrentState() {
    return branches.get(branches.size());
}

public StateNode getState(int point) {
    return branches.get(point);
}

public StateNode[] getStates() {
    return branches.values().toArray(new StateNode[branches.size()]);
}

public int getMaximum() {
    return maxsteps;
}

public int promote() {
    return promote(1);
}

public int promote(int factor) {

    for (int i = 0; i < factor; i++) {
        branches.remove(branches.size());
    }

    return branches.size();
}

public StateTree setState(StateNode state) {

    branches.put((branches.size() + 1), state);

    return this;
}

public void setMaxSteps(int maxsteps) {
    this.maxsteps = maxsteps;
}
```

}

How it currently works
When a new transaction is requested there's a module known as the  transaction processing engine that uses the xml and this structure to process the transaction. So what happens is we create a new state tree for every transaction that comes into the system and persist it to a database then for every step, error or hook being executed we create a new state node and save it into the state tree. I hope this is clear enough.

Actual Execution
To determine which state to execute and at what step I have a recursive method called resolve execution . I hope it is intuitive to the reader:

```
private void resolveExecution(Context ctx, Map<String, String> header, StateTree tree) throws Exception {

    StateNode state = tree.getCurrentState();

    /**
     * Resolves the states priority by doing the following check. if a hook
     * exists and has not been executed then change the state to hook and
     * then invoke the hook logic else if not check that a replay exists an
     * that it has not been executed and if that is met then invoke the
     * replay manager and it's logic else invoke the the current state.
     */

    State statename = !state.getHook().isEmpty() && !state.isHookExecuted()
            ? State.HOOK : !state.isScriptExecuted() ? state.getStateName()
            : state.getStateName() == State.ERROR && !state.getReplay().isEmpty() && !state.isReplayExecuted()
            ? State.REPLAY
            : state.getStateName();

    switch (statename) {

        case STEP:

            logger.debug(Utility.LOG.transaction(header.get("code"), header.get("type"), header.get("id"), header.get("msisdn"), "Begin resolving execution for step."));

            if (state.isScriptExecuted()) {

                /**
                 * Add new state of the next step id and update the state
                 * map
                 */
                tree.setState(new StateNode(
                        State.STEP,
                        Configurations.HANDLER.getStepConfigurationsFromId(header.get("code"),
                                state.getNextid())
                ));

                this.resolveAndExecuteScript(ctx, header, tree);

            } else {

                state.setScriptExecuted(true);

                this.resolveAndExecuteScript(ctx, header, tree);
            }

            logger.debug(Utility.LOG.transaction(header.get("code"), header.get("type"), header.get("id"), header.get("msisdn"), "End of resolving execution for step."));

            break;
        case ERROR:

            logger.debug(Utility.LOG.transaction(header.get("code"), header.get("type"), header.get("id"), header.get("msisdn"), "Begin resolving execution for error."));

            if (state.isScriptExecuted()) {

                if ("-9".equals(state.getNextid())) {

                    this.exit(ctx, header);

                } else {

                    tree.promote();

                    this.resolveExecution(ctx, header, tree);
                }

            } else {

                state.setErrorExecuted(true);

                this.resolveAndExecuteScript(ctx, header, tree);
            }

            logger.debug(Utility.LOG.transaction(header.get("code"), header.get("type"), header.get("id"), header.get("msisdn"), "End of resolving execution for error."));

            break;
        case HOOK:

            logger.debug(Utility.LOG.transaction(header.get("code"), header.get("type"), header.get("id"), header.get("msisdn"), "Begin resolving execution for hook."));

            if (state.isScriptExecuted()) {

                if ("true".equals(state.getAdvance())) {

                    tree.promote();

                    this.resolveExecution(ctx, header, tree);

                } else {

                    this.exit(ctx, header, this.resolveStatus(7));
                }

            } else {

                state.setHookExecuted(true);

                Map<String, String> configs = Configurations.HANDLER.getHookConfigurations(state.getHook());

                tree.setState(new StateNode(statename,
                        state.getId(),
                        configs.get("name"),
                        configs.get("script"),
                        configs.get("result"),
                        state.getNextid(),
                        state.getCode(),
                        state.getHook(),
                        state.getReplay(),
                        StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(configs.get("advance"), "true")));

                this.resolveAndExecuteScript(ctx, header, tree);
            }

            logger.debug(Utility.LOG.transaction(header.get("code"), header.get("type"), header.get("id"), header.get("msisdn"), "End of resolving execution for hook."));

            break;
        case REPLAY:

            logger.debug(Utility.LOG.transaction(header.get("code"), header.get("type"), header.get("id"), header.get("msisdn"), "Begin resolving execution for replay."));

            state.setReplayExecuted(true);

            if (!this.replay(ctx, header, state.getStateName() == State.REPLAY ? tree
                    : tree.setState(new StateNode(
                                    statename,
                                    state.getId(),
                                    state.getName(),
                                    "?".equals(state.getScript()) ? tree.getState(2).getScript() : state.getScript(),
                                    state.getResult(),
                                    state.getNextid(),
                                    state.getCode(),
                                    state.getHook(),
                                    state.getReplay())))) {

                tree.promote();

                this.resolveExecution(ctx, header, tree);
            }

            logger.debug(Utility.LOG.transaction(header.get("code"), header.get("type"), header.get("id"), header.get("msisdn"), "End of resolving execution for replay."));

            break;
    }
}
```

Question
I have a working solution already  but I feel it's not the best. Now that we are doing performance tests I have detected that the processing is slow and I believe it can be better. What data structure would you recommend to map this xml and/or a design pattern ? I hope this is doesn't feel like an open ended question.
Thank you

Comment: What data structure are you using atm? (Just to have a point of reference)

Comment: For StateNode definitely Builder pattern would be much better instead of so many parametrized constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does feel a bit like a flavor question.

If I understand correctly you have data driven flow , by which I mean you have some data (in this case in form of xml's and scripts) that dictates what actions will be taken (so it's not known at compile time, but you use a pseudo language to describe this flow).

My usual approach is to make a queue of commands and populate it all at once , then execute it , rather then executing command , load next script, execute command. This however involves to make your own pseudo-language compiler so to speak :).

If your xmls are somewhat trivial you can get away with it easily.

For your xml example , the queue of command would result in

1 - 2  - 3

Because you have no branching (it seems to me that you just go through them regardless)

You will have to preload some scripts (for extra optimization) :

```
 $err-5000
 $notify
 etc
```

Now you can decide at a global level what scripts will be cached and which won't.

Comment: There's branching involved when you execute a hook, because it's similar to step but has more attributes and other functionality. Would you still suggest the same now that there's branching ?

Comment: Yes , you can do the same even with branching, it just that your command queue gets more complicated (you will basically either have jumps or store the command queue in a tree). The command queue is useful to use cached instructions so you don't reload commonly used scripts and also to know up front what scrpits you need to load (so it's 1 load time, then execute vs multiple little loads ). It depends however how deep your hierarchy goes, it might end up counter productive if your tree uses ALLOT of branches (you end up keeping all scripts in memory).

Comment: Thank you chief, this looks very promising.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a `Step` class containing all the attributes and store all your steps in a [**LinkedHashSet**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html):

```
public class Step{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String script;
  private String result;
 // getters and setters and constructors
}
```

And then make a **LinkedHashSet** of Steps and they will be linked one to an other in the order you inserted them:

```
Step step1=new Step(1, "momo.debit", "step-1", "0000");
Step step2=new Step(2, "deposit", "step-2", "0000");
// create all your steps here
LinkedHashSet<Step> steps = new LinkedHashSet<Step>();
steps.add(step1);
steps.add(step2);
```

Take a look at these examples for further information:

- [**TutorialsPoint Example**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedhashset_class.htm).
- [**Java2novice Exmaple**](http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/linked-hashset/basic-operations/).

Comment: thank you but I already have this place, the linkedhashset though is a good idea , performs better than the linkedlist.